# Tests succeed when run from Test View but fail when run from test list editor or command line

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, integration-testing

I have a test suite, comprised of both unit tests and integration tests, in a project using C# on .NET 4.0 with Visual Studio 2010. The test suite uses MSTest. When I run all tests in solution (either by hitting the button in the testing toolbar or using the Ctrl-R A shortcut chord) all of the tests, integration and unit, pass successfully.

When I either attempt to run the same tests from the command line with `mstest` (explicitly using the only `.testsettings` file present) or attempt to run them from the Test List Editor or using the `.vsmdi` file the integration tests fail.

The integration tests test the UI and so have dependencies on deployment items and such, whereas the unit tests do not. However, I cannot seem to pin down what is actually different between these two methods of running the tests.

When I inspect the appropriate `Out` directories from the test run, not all of the files are present.

What would cause some of the files that deploy correctly in one situation from Visual Studio to not deploy correctly in another?

Comment: How does your tests fail? Is an assertion violated, or is it rather "tests can't be launched because dll xxx can't be loaded"? In the first case, can you copy the code a failing test?

Comment: It appears as though some content files (in this case, an SQL Server compact database) are copied in the successful scenario but omitted in the failing scenario. This is, itself, odd since there is only one testsettings file in the solution and it is configured to allow deployments. Moreover, the folder for the database is included using DeploymentItem attributes.

Comment: Also worth noting is that the issue isn't tied to the order of the tests. Running the integration tests manually, one at a time, in any sequence, still works. The integration tests are not dependent on one another. The issue only arises when using the command line or Test List Editor to run the tests.

Comment: You might want to check your use of statics in the tests.  When running the test suite, it is often run in one process instance, and so statics will stick around from one test run to another.  This is often overlooked when writing the tests because you will get the "unedited" statics when not running multiple tests together.

Answer (score 3):

The static content started being copied shortly after I wrote the comments above. The other major issue I ran into was that the integration test project referenced libraries that were dependencies of the system-under-test (with copy-local set to true) in order to ensure that the DLLs would be present when  they were needed. For some reason, these stubbornly refused to copy when the tests were run through Test List or `mstest`.

What I eventually did to work around it was include `[DeploymentItem]` attributes for the DLLs that I needed. This got things working no matter how the tests were run. What I am still unclear on, that may have answered the underlying solution, or provided a better solution, is how Test View/mstest differ from the regular test runner (assuming that the correct `.settings` file was passed to `mstest`.). I'm putting these notes/workarounds in an answer, but I'll leave the question open in case anyone can address the underlying cause for how the different test execution paths differ.